# dmloptions trigger - test failing

Tags: apex, trigger, lead-auto-response

I'm attempting to create a case trigger to enable auto-response rules to be kicked off when inserting a case via the API. However, my test class seems to be failing. Anyone have any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger MyCaseAutoResponse on Case (after insert) {
if (trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert) {    
    List<Case> newlyInsertedCases = [SELECT Id From Case WHERE Id IN :trigger.new];

    Database.DMLOptions autoResponseOptions = new Database.DMLOptions();
    autoResponseOptions.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = true;

    for (Case c : newlyInsertedCases ) {
        Database.update(c, autoResponseOptions); 
    } 

}
```

And here is my test class:

```
@IsTest
private with sharing class MyCaseAutoResponseTest{
    @IsTest
    private static void testCaseTriggerViaDML()
    {
        Case testCase = new Case();
        insert testCase;

        Database.DMLOptions dmo = testCase.getOptions();

        System.assertNotEquals(null, dmo, 'DMLOption is null');
        System.assert(dmo.EmailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail, true);    
    }

}
```

The first assert statement fails, since the DML options for the created Case record is null.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty sure auto response doesn't actually fire in a test context, at least the corresponding activity is not created. I've not tried using DMLOptions before though.

Comment: I just reviewed how I tested/asserted it in the past, and I queried the Case after the insert and asserted that the Case owner had changed. I'm not 100% sure if that's the best way though.

Comment: Thanks @Girbot. Nothing on the actual Case record is changing, so I'm not sure what I would test against. I was hoping the DML options would be there, but apparently they're not.

Answer (score 1):

`getOptions()` won't return anything without a prior `setOptions()`.

Your trigger is updating a completely different variable `newlyInsertedCases` than what is in `Trigger.new[0]` which is `testCase`- hence why `testCase.getOptions()` returns null

As for verifying that the autoresponse rules actually executed in the test, you'll need to verify something persistent like `EmailMessage` as a child of Case.  Emails are never sent in testmethods but `EmailMessage` should exist.